# Convergence of Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

If I know that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to $a$,

then to prove that the sequence $\{ca_n\}$ (for a constant $c$) converges to $ca$, I would basically want $|ca_n - ca| < \epsilon$... So, to prove this we have

$|c||a_n-a| < \epsilon$, so if we FIX $\epsilon$, we know since $a_n$ converges to $a$, there exists an $N$, such that whenever $n≥N$, then $|a_n-a| < \frac {\epsilon}{|c|}$.

Thus we have $|ca_n-ca| < \epsilon$...

(sorry for lack of rigor in some parts)

So my question is: since we know that $a_n$ converges to $a$, we can make it small as we want. In this case we can make it smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{|c|}$ using a specific $N$. But, is this specific $\epsilon$ still arbitrary? In order to prove convergence of a sequence, given any $\epsilon >0$, there exists an $N$ such that...

So how does this work for this proof then, since we are choosing a specific $\epsilon$? (but is it still arbitrary?)

Comment: See this please: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I changed {$a_n$} (with the {curly braces} _outside_ of MathJax) to $\{a_n\}$ (with the braces within MathJax).  That way you get matching fonts and proper spacing. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to be careful in your own mind about when you are stating a definition versus when you are using a fact about a sequence that *follows* from that definition. Let's take it from the top:

- You want to show that for any $\epsilon$ there exists $N$ such that whenever $n\ge N$ then $|ca_n - ca| = |c|\cdot |a_n-a| < \epsilon$. So far so good.
- As you point out, this is the same as saying that for any $\epsilon$ there exists $N$ such that whenever $n\ge N$ then $|a_n-a| < \frac{\epsilon}{|c|}$.
- So how will you prove that statement? We want to prove that something holds for *any* $\epsilon>0$. So choose an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$; we want to find an $N$ that works for *that* $\epsilon$.
- You know that $a_n\to a$, so that means that for any $\epsilon'>0$ there is an $N$ such that whenever $n\ge N$ then $|a_n-a| < \epsilon'$. Since this statement holds for *any* $\epsilon'>0$, in particular it holds when $\epsilon' = \frac{\epsilon}{|c|}$.
- We conclude that there is some $N$ such that whenever $n\ge N$ then
  $$|a_n-a| < \epsilon' = \frac{\epsilon}{|c|},$$
  which is what you were trying to prove.

Comment: Would you agree with the following statement: since a_n --> a, for any e' >0 there is an N such that whenver n>= N then |a_n-a| < e'. Since it holds for ANY e', we can let e' be in the "form" of e/|c| ?

Comment: Well done!  This seems to be a concept that challenges a number of students.  +1

Comment: @Dr.MV Just to be clear (sorry if being obnoxious), my statement is correct?

Comment: @user166712 Yes!  You seem to have it now!  Good work. And no, you're not being obnoxious at all.  ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV my confusion comes from this: So if we let epsilon be in this "form", then it is arbitrary? But then, would N be a specific value or arbitrary as well? (since for each arbitrarily chosen epsilon, there is a corresponding N value)

Comment: @user166712 The statement about $a_n$ holds for *any* epsilon, so it holds for $\frac{\epsilon}{|c|}$. So no, this particular choice of epsilon is not arbitrary - it is chosen to make the proof work. But since the implication is true for any arbitrary epsilon, it is true for this one. As a result, the $N$ you get is the $N$ that works for this specific choice of epsilon. See if my edits make it any clearer.

Comment: @rogerl so epsilon is arbitrarily chosen, but epsilon/|c| is a specific choice? But if you have a constant times something arbitrary wouldn't that still be arbitrary?

Comment: @rogerl to clarify, we want to show for every epsilon>0 the inequality holds. So we choose an arbitrary epsilon, and we want to show for that particular epsilon there exists an N. In this case, the arbitrary epsilon that we have chosen is epsilon/|c| and since a_n converges we know there exists an N for that particularly chosen epsilon. However, since this is arbitrarily chosen, it holds for every epsilon>0 ?

Comment: @user166712 that (your last comment) is exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for this : Simply note that

$|ca_n-ca|=|c||a_n-a|<c\epsilon $

Try to understand the  inner meaning of convergence .It says the distance between the terms of the sequence get very small after a certain period .

Since $\epsilon $ is arbitrary and chosen very small so terms of the sequence $ca_n$ also get very close after a certain period (i.e. same as $a_n$) .

For technical purpose note that as $\epsilon $ is arbitrary so is $c\epsilon$ for any $c\in \mathbb R$